# LibGDX HTMLLauncher Failed to build

Tags: libgdx

I created a brand new LibGDX project using the GDX-Setup.jar file for a Desktop and HTML project. After configuring the project directory, I am able to run the DesktopLauncher fine, and the default image shows in the window. I also tried use the HTMLLauncher using (I also tried this using a project I was coding):

```
./gradlew html:superDev
```

but the build fails with:

```
Task :html:draftCompileGwt FAILED
Compiling module com.mygdx.game.GdxDefinitionSuperdev
[ERROR] Hint: Check that your module inherits 'com.google.gwt.core.Core' either directly or indirectly (most often by inheriting module 'com.google.gwt.user.User')
```

I am unsure why I am not able to run the HTML application.

Any ideas with the error above? I've also posted the basic project here:
https://github.com/EricSchafur/BasicLibGdxProject

Thank you.

Comment: What java version are you on?

Answer (score 0):

I believe GWT 2.8.1 supports java version below 9.
Try to downgrade (or use alternative java path) the version if you use something newer